How to add string at a specific position in each line
With
awk '{ printf "%-15s %s\n", $1, $2 }' renamed | sort -V

... I get good output from the file renamed.
It looks like:
file1           file1.new

But I want to have the output changed to this:
file1           -->  file1.new

I want to add -->   at position 15 in each line.
How to do that?

Try printf "%-15s--> %s\n" in awk command.

That is it, thank you!

What should happen when the input contains a $1 that's 15 or more characters long? What if either file name contains spaces?

in my case, it will never be longer than 12 characters.

The printf format string %-15s %s\n specifies that you want to output two strings delimited by a space and terminated by a newline character.
The first string should be given a width of 15 characters, and the minus sign signifies that it should be left-justified within those 15 characters (the remaining characters to the right of the string will be filled out with spaces).
To insert -->   in front of the second string, after the single space, just modify the format to %-15s -->  %s\n.
Example of this:
$ printf '%s\n' "one thing" "another thing" | awk '{ printf "%-15s %s\n", $1, $2 }'
one             thing
another         thing

$ printf '%s\n' "one thing" "another thing" | awk '{ printf "%-15s -->  %s\n", $1, $2 }'
one             -->  thing
another         -->  thing

Note that the -->   is actually added at position 17, not 15.  Position 15 is reserved for the first string while position 16 will have that space character in the formatting string.  To add -->   at position 15, you would need to reduce the space for the first string to 13: %-13s -->  %s\n.

Consider using column to determine the appropriate first field width instead of hard-coding 15 so it can handle fields longer than 15 chars if necessary, e.g. using any version of column:
$ cat renamed
file1 file1.new
12345678951234567890 file2.new


$ column -t renamed
file1                 file1.new
12345678951234567890  file2.new


$ column -t renamed | sed 's/  */&-->  /'
file1                 -->  file1.new
12345678951234567890  -->  file2.new

If you have GNU column then it has a -o option to specify the output field separator so then you don't need the pipe to sed:
$ column -t -o '  -->  ' renamed
file1                 -->  file1.new
12345678951234567890  -->  file2.new

It can also handle blanks inside the fields if your fields are tab-separated by adding -s$'\t' or there are all sorts of other things we could do to handle all sorts of different input, ask a new question with more details on your input format if you need more help.
